# How to add string name on this shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I have the script for packing tar like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
last=`ls [JKT-MMM1]*.tar | sed s/.tar//g | sort -g | tail -1`
if(($last%1==0))
then
     tar -cf `date '+%W%b%d'`.tar [JKT-MMM1]*.tar
fi
```

After I execute this script, the output file name comes out like this :38Sep28

So **my question is how to add the name to this file?** (I want the output file like this : 38Sep28.JKT-MM1)

Thanks

Comment: I dont see you using `$last` in the `tar` command. Can you please be more elaborate?

Comment: so how to add the string name ?

Comment: `tar -cf \`date '+%W%b%d'\`.JKT-MM1.tar [JKT-MMM1]*.tar`

Comment: From what i understand, i guess you require `tar -cf $(date '+%W%b%d').${last}.tar [JKT-MMM1]*.tar`

Answer (score 0):

Not the complete solution, but just a clue:

```
DATE=`date +%W%b%d`
NAME=`echo ${last}.tar`
FILE=`echo ${DATE}${NAME}`

tar -cf ${FILE} [JKT-MMM1]*.tar
```